# how to extract specific elements from a file

Tags: text-processing

I have a file with the following snap

```
Name    age  class
John    12   3
Mark    10   1
Philip  15   6
```

delimiter between the columns are multiple spaces.

I want to print the highest number in class category

Please help and tell me how can I get the desired output.

Comment: so you want entire line with highest class score? or just `6` for given data? please [edit] your question to response and  show expected output

Answer (score 3):

```bsh
awk 'NR > 1 && (max == "" || $NF > max) { max = $NF } END { print max }' file
```

This reads your file, and whenever the last field of any line, except the first line (which is a header line), is a numeric value greater than any one seen before, that value is remembered in the variable `max`.  The value is also remembered if no value has been remembered before.

At the end, the value of the variable `max`, which is the greatest value seen in the last field of any line (except the first), is printed.

This assumes that the `class` column is always at the end of each line.

The special variables `NF` and `NR` are the number of fields in the current record, and the number of records read so far, respectively. The value `$NF` is the value of the last field in the current record.

To get the whole line that has the largest number in the last column, only a couple of small modifications have to be made to the above code to also remember and print the relevant data:

```bsh
awk 'NR > 1 && (max == "" || $NF > max) { max = $NF; line = $0 } END { print line }' file
```

Answer (score -2):

`sort` has this function by defining the key position. You may try this:

```
sort --key=3 file
```

Comment: not a complete answer, this does only sort the file on third field and actually doesn't answer the question at all

Comment: This seems to require a specific variant of `sort` (GNU?) and would fail if the any of the other fields were allowed to have embedded spaces (e.g. for names like Mary Anne in the first column). The answer also needs to show how to extract the wanted value once the data has been sorted.